# GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 extension in compute shaders does not work properly

Tags: android, opengl-es, mali

I use the `GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3` extension to access camera pictures in GLSL. For fragment shaders it works fine. Here is my simple fragment shader:

```
#version 320 es
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 : require

precision mediump float;

uniform samplerExternalOES cameraTexture;

in vec2 v_TexCoordinate;
out vec4 fragmentColor;

void main() {
    fragmentColor = texture(cameraTexture, v_TexCoordinate);
}
```

I can see the picture from the camera.

However when I insert a simple compute shader stage in pipeline that only copies data from that external image to a new texture which I display, I can see only black screen. I also generate a red line in the compute shader for debugging.

Here is the code of that compute shader:

```
#version 320 es
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 : require

precision mediump float;

layout(local_size_x = LOCAL_SIZE, local_size_y = LOCAL_SIZE) in;
layout(binding=1, rgba8) uniform mediump writeonly image2D outputImage;

uniform samplerExternalOES cameraTexture;

void main() {
    ivec2 position = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);

    vec4 cameraColor = texture(cameraTexture, vec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy)/1024.);
    imageStore(outputImage, position, cameraColor);

    // generate a red line to see that in general the texture
    // that is produced by the compute shader is displayed on the
    // screen
    if (position.x == 100) imageStore(outputImage, position, vec4(1,0,0,1));
}
```

So it seems like it accesses the texture in the same way, but vec(0,0,0,1) is returned by `texture()` instead. So the screen is black.

In both cases I bind the texture like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mCameraTextureId)
glUniform1i(cameraUniformHandle, 0)
```

Why does this extension not work properly in my compute shader? Is it supposed to work in compute shaders at all?

My platform is Samsung Galaxy S7 (Mali GPU).

Comment: Which Galaxy S7? There are two versions, one based on Snapdragon (Adreno GU) and one based on Exynos (Mali GPU)

Comment: @solidpixel The phone has Mali GPU

Comment: I made the same experience btw, but it should work (see specs)